# Select word of a textarea on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a text (sentence) in a textbox. How do I select or highlight a **word** under the mouse pointer? I am using JSF.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Since you are stressing "word", do you perhaps already know how to select the letter under the cursor? I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: two questions:
- is the textbox static html or a textbox for input?
- As you got JSF and Javascript as tags: Are you searching for a client or for a server based solution?

Comment: @JanD I am searching for client side solution. The jsf tag was not added my me. I mentioned jsf in my question as I heard that jsf has poor jQuery support. I am searching for javascript solution.

Comment: @pimvdb my plan is to find the index of the cursor position of the textarea. then go left and right from that index. Stop on getting space on both side. Find both the indexes and select that range. But I am not able to do it. I am stuck in the first step.

Comment: Poor jQuery support? This makes no sense. Even more, the most popular JSF component libraries PrimeFaces and RichFaces ships with jQuery builtin.

Comment: @BalusC I am extremely sorry. I am new in this subject. I have little experience in wicket, but jsf is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with JSF, but you can have a look at what I have done.

I am not sure how to 'enable' html tags in a textarea, like you will see in my link. But I did it in a DIV tag too, so you can see that the highlight works.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkYHG/1/

Process : Read all words, place span's around each word and bind the event.

This can give you some direction ;)

Comment: thanks. I can attach an `onmouseover` event to the `span`s but firstly the div should not be visible, secondly if I placed the div and textarea in the same layer and hide the div then that mouse event is not generating.